# How to pass unique_ptr object as argument to a class that is a library

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I read all the questions and answers related to passing unique_ptr as argument to a class constructor and those answers worked for classes within the exe. But here im trying to pass an unique_ptr object to a class constructor that is pre-compiled as static library.

This class in the library looks something like this,

```
// Class declaration (in a header file)
class TScreen
{
   private:
      std::unique_ptr<TProcess> m_process;
   public:
      __fastcall TScreen(int a, std::unique_ptr<TProcess> i_process);
};    

// The constructor definition (in a separate .cpp file)
__fastcall TScreen::TScreen(int a, std::unique_ptr<TProcess> i_process): 
m_process(std::move(i_process)) 
{ 
}
```

I will be trying to instantiate the class TScreen in the exe like this,

```
void TScreen_Main::CallScreen()
{
   std::unique_ptr<TProcess> objprocess (new TProcess());
   std::unique_ptr<TScreen> objscreen (new TScreen(0, std::move(objprocess)));
}
```

I compiled the library and imported it to the exe. When i compile the exe, it gives me a link error like this,

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall TScreen::TScreen(int, std::unique_ptr<TProcess, std::default_delete<TProcess> >)' referenced from TSCREEN_MAIN.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
```

I tried the same with boost::shared_ptr as well and it gives me the same error. But it works fine with raw pointers, but not with smart pointers and i cannot figure out why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting `inline` in there after `__fastcall`. This is a linking problem. So, somehow that function is never making it into an obj file. Even though it probably doesn't ever need to because it's pretty easily inlined. If you declare it `inline` explicitly, that tells the linker that if it actually needs the definition it needs to emit it everywhere, that the definition won't just be sitting in some random `.obj` file someplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is a linking issue. Now, exactly what's going on is difficult for me to say because I never work in a Windows environment, and linking is something that (while very similar) has some distinct differences between a Unix/Linux and a Windows environment.

My guess is that if you explicitly declare your constructor to be `inline`, and declare that the definition is `inline`, it will work correctly.

This presumes that the fact that you put the declaration of the class and definition together indicates that the definition is in the header file with the class.

When the compiler sees that it's declared `inline` it will emit a definition into every compilation unit where it's needed. The linker should then eliminate all the duplicate definitions.

If you really are defining the constructor in some `.cpp` file separate from the `.hpp` file that the class is in, and you compiler that `.cpp` file into `.obj` file that eventually makes it into a `.lib` or `.dll` that you link against when creating the executable, then I don't know what the problem is. If this is the case, you should use the tools that should come with your development environment to see what symbols are actually in the library or the dll because somehow the symbol for the constructor definition isn't there.

Comment: Thank you, your answer kind of gave me an idea of what i was looking for. My constructor definition is in a seperate `.cpp` so the keyword im looking for is not `inline`. I had to declare the constructor `explicit` and now the linking happened.

Comment: @RaviSangar - That shouldn't have had any effect. `explicit` has nothing to do with linking or symbol visibility. It only tells the compiler that the constructor can't be used for implicit conversions, which is sort of pointless for a multiple argument constructor since they'll never (AFAIK) be considered for implicit conversions anyway. My guess is that you modifying the `.cpp` file forced your IDE to recompile and regenerate your libraries.

Comment: Actually as a guideline for coding to improve quality of the code we declare all classes constructors `explicit` so i thought of adding it before trying your suggestion and it worked. I also tried adding the declaration and definition with `inline` keyword in the same file and that too worked.